# Why is $f(x)=1/\sqrt{|x|} $ local integrable and $f^2$ not?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Why is $f(x)=1/\sqrt{|x|} $ local integrable and $f^2$ not?

I think i have to show this $$\int_\mathbb{R}|f(x)|  d\lambda<\infty$$

But how i calculate with it?

Comment: For any number $L$, we have$$\int_{-L}^L \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}\,dx=2\int_0^L \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx=4\sqrt{L}<\infty$$

Comment: Is $d\lambda$ the same as $dx$?  What do you mean by local integrable?  Assuming the integral is with respect to $x$, neither function is integrable over the real line.

Comment: @herbsteinberg $f$ is [locally integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function) if it is integrable on compact subsets of its domain.

Comment: We wrote in University Lebequeintegrals with $d\lambda$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split into positive and negative $x$. For $x>0$, $f(x) =1/\sqrt x$, and for $x<0$ $f(x) =1/\sqrt{-x}$. This is not integrable over all reals but it is locally integrable.

Comment: To complete the answer $\int_{-L}^L\frac{1}{|x|}dx$ is infinite.

Comment: So its only to solve a Rieman integral with limes?

Comment: Or should i calculate the measure?

Comment: @mathbob Whenever both exist, Riemann and Lebesgue integrals are equal.